# Error App Domain when creating an app

Tags: iphone, url, facebook-apps

When I am creating an app, I put the URL as specified and it comes up with the following:

Error  App Domain: http://coolapp.hobbycraftstore.com/ is not a valid domain.  Why isn't it valid? I have also tried domain name http//coolfbapp.com/ and this didn't work either

Comment: try only "hobbycraftstore.com"

Answer (score 1):

a domain does not contain the protocol! So just remove http:// and it will work:

```
domain: coolapp.hobbycraftstore.com
```

The original author is absolutely correct.  However, even seeing other answers with this information, I was still getting errors and didn't know why.

With the help of other answers posted, I finally got it working.  Here's the steps that include the complete solution that worked for me.

1. From the Facebook development page "Apps-YourAppName", click on Basic in the LEFT Nav.
2. There are 3 sections on this page: Basic Info, Cloud Services, and "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"
3. In the Select how your app integrates with Facebook section, select "Website"
4. Enter your fully qualified domain name in the Site URL dialog box. Example: http://www.mydomain.com OR http://mydomain.com (my site does not include the www so I didn't add it).
5. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button. You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
6. Now, in the Basic Information section at the top of this screen, you can now add your App Domain. This should be formatted as mydomain.com. Do not add "http://" and do not add "/" at the end of the domain name.
7. NOTE: My site does not use the www, so I cannot confirm that it's required in Step #6. Try it both ways if you're unsure.
8. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button. You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
9. At this point the error was NOT displayed as it was before.

Hope this helps!